# live drawing on a svg file, coordinates problem

Tags: svg, coordinates, svg.js

I am having some trouble drawing real-world objects on an SVG map.

context: 
I have a map which I converted to an svg file (inkscape), this map is then displayed on a web-page with 100% width/height.

I then want to draw points on this map, those points have coordinates in mm (on a very different and bigger scale), so I need to apply a scale factor and a conversion to... pixels?

that's where the difficulty is for me, SVG file uses "user units" measure system, it is then drawn scaling everything to the frame where it is loaded, I would like to scale my real-world point coordinates system to a "user units"-like reference system so that such points can be dynamically drawn on the page.

the web page is html/svg + javascript and I am using svg.js library to draw everything on it.

any clue about how to make ma transformation to align everything up?

Comment: I would advice to have a look at the `viewBox` property, you can simplify everything. If you want a useful answer, you should provide a minimal example other people can tinker with. You can use so's tools (snippet) or external sites, like jfiddle, codepen,...

Comment: You can use millimeter in svg. The Browser will do the conversion for you. Otherwise you would need to know how big a pixel is on the screen it is displayed. However, keep in mind that some functions of svg.js might not work properly with mm.